# EF 6 Code-First Many to Many relationship with same entity on non-primary key

Tags: c#, .net, database, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

I have an EF 6 Task entity, which looks like this:

```
public class Task
{
    public Guid TaskId {get; set;}
    public TaskTypeEnum TaskType {get; set;}
    public TaskStatusEnum TaskStatus {get; set;}

    public virtual ICollection<Task> Dependencies {get; set;}
}
```

Tasks of a certain type can be dependent on all other tasks of a certain type to finish running before they run, and those dependencies should be defined in a table like this:

```
public class TaskTypeDependency
{
    public TaskTypeEnum TaskType {get; set;}
    public TaskTypeEnum DependsOnTaskType {get; set;}
}
```

Example of what I want- Task A has Type 1, Task B and C have Type 2. I have a TaskTypeDependency of

```
TaskType | DependsOnTaskType
----------------------------
1        |  2
```

At runtime, I want to get all the tasks that task is dependent on, which for Task A would be Task B and Task C, to check if the dependent tasks have completed. Is there a way to set this relationship up in Code-First, maybe with Fluent API? Or am I stuck using LINQ to sort this all out without a virtual property?

Comment: So *all tasks* of type 1 are dependent on *all tasks* of type 2? If so, you can simply check if al tasks of type 2 have completed if you want to know if *any* task of type 1 can be completed. You don't need this `Dependencies` collection.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Welcome to StackOverflow!

## As far as I know, EF cannot handle relationships of this kind.

Your problem isn't that the principal key isn't the primary key. Your main problem is that those keys (`TaskType`s) **are not unique**.

## Solution proposal

You can work around this limitation by encapsulating the logic of loading the dependent tasks in a repository. While many people [advice against](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/180851/why-shouldnt-i-use-the-repository-pattern-with-entity-framework/220126) building a repository pattern on top of EF, and most of the times I'm on that side too, this is a great example of why it can be useful.

I would create a method that populates dependencies using LINQ, maybe an extension method, something along the lines of:

```
private static void LoadDependentTasks(this Task task, IEnumerable<Task> allTasks){
    task.Dependencies = allTasks.Where(yourCustomSelector).ToList();
}
```

Then in your repository you can use this method on the Tasks you loaded before you return them. E.g:

```
public Task GetById(Guid taskId){
    Task t = _context.Tasks.Find(taskId);
    t.LoadDependentTasks(_context.Tasks);
}
```

Then when your business logic calls your repository, it will receive objects that already have their `Dependencies` property filled.

There is **one optimization** that is worth mentioning here, though. It isn't as important for getting a single task, but makes a lot of difference when loading all of them. If you implement the GetAll method naively, as follows, **it will retrieve the list of Tasks from the server *n* times**, which is not great.

```
public Task GetAll(){
    List<Task> allTasks = _context.Tasks.ToList();
    foreach(var task in allTasks)
        task.LoadDependentTasks(_context.Tasks);
    return allTasks;
}
```

You should pass the already existing `allTasks` variable to the method instead. If - in another scenario - you don't have a list of tasks already, another solution is to call `_context.Tasks.Load()`, and use `_context.Tasks.Load` thereafter.